# How do you deploy an ASP.Net MVC 4 app on IIS 6.1 (SP1) / Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, deployment, windows-server-2008

How do you deploy an ASP.Net MVC 4 app on IIS 6.1 (SP1)(Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition)?

Comment: Shouldn't it go to serverfault?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean @bahrep I am new to this. Anyway I am trying to deploy it to the production server on my company's network. Any suggestions?

Comment: @bahrep is talking about the one of the other Q&A sites that are part of the StackExchange family http://serverfault.com/.  It is common for questions to be moved from one site to another.

Comment: Uhh.. IIS6.1? On Windows Server 2008 R2?  IIS on this is 7.5, although the OS version is 6.1

Answer (score 2):

This website was very useful in helping me to solve the problem.

http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNETMVC/216_Hosting_and_Deployment_of_an_ASPNET_MVC_Application_in_IIS6_and_IIS7.aspx